# How can I extract a zip file with DotNetZip in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, unzip

I have a C# project in visual studio and I want to change target framework from **.NET Framework 4.6** to **.NET Framework 3.5**. In the past I used this code to exctract zip file:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

But now I can not use **ZipFile** class. So I added **DotNetZip** library to my project but I don't know How to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# .Net 3.5 Unzip zip file no 3rd party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778459/c-sharp-net-3-5-unzip-zip-file-no-3rd-party)

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd shows a simple extraction example.

Comment: "but I don't know How to use it." What happened when you tried to find out?

Answer (score 0):

As Steve said in comments I used [this link](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd).

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipPath))
{

    zip.ExtractAll(mainPath);

}
```