# How to Unzip a Folder in an SSIS Script Task with a Password

Tags: c#, ssis

I am in need of some help. I have found numerous guides on how to unzip a static ZIP folder from one place to another using an SSIS C# script task, but I cannot find one that handles zip files with passwords. I need to unzip a folder with one file inside of it and have that file placed in a new directory. I have figured this out for files with no password, but how to do this with a password? The password is the same every month.

Edit: Is there a way to do it without 3rd party stuff?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899765/how-to-unzip-a-folder-with-multiple-files-using-ssis-script-task-c-sharp-2005-or/20903436#20903436

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160490/decompressing-password-protected-zip-files-with-net-4-5

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a third party tool unless you want to write it yourself.  I use Ionic.zip

[Decompressing password-protected ZIP files with .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160490/decompressing-password-protected-zip-files-with-net-4-5)